# Table in latex issuing error because of unknown mistake in column typesetting

Tags: tables

the following code 1 returns proper table with predefine `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}`:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h!]
\Large
\centering
    $P_I=$1 atm\\
    $v_i=$2.2v\\
    \bigskip
    \begin{tabular}{|| C{2cm} | C{2cm} | C{2cm} | m{2cm} ||}\hline
    $V_I$ & $V_F$ & $P_F$ & $v_i$  \\ \hline\hline
    20mL     & 15mL     & atm      & 3.54v \\\hline
    20mL     & 10mL     & atm      & 6.2v  \\\hline
    20mL     & 18mL     & atm      & 3v    \\\hline
    15mL     & 10mL     & atm      & 4.2v  \\\hline
    10mL     & 5mL      & atm      & 5.8v  \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\Large $P_F\*V_F=P_I\*V_I$
\end{center}
```

[image: output]

but when the last column type is changed like following the output is collapsed:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h!]
\Large
\centering
    $P_I=$1 atm\\
    $v_i=$2.2v\\
    \bigskip
    \begin{tabular}{|| C{2cm} | C{2cm} | C{2cm} | C{2cm} ||}\hline
    $V_I$ & $V_F$ & $P_F$ & $v_i$  \\ \hline\hline
    20mL     & 15mL     & atm      & 3.54v \\\hline
    20mL     & 10mL     & atm      & 6.2v  \\\hline
    20mL     & 18mL     & atm      & 3v    \\\hline
    15mL     & 10mL     & atm      & 4.2v  \\\hline
    10mL     & 5mL      & atm      & 5.8v  \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\Large $P_F\*V_F=P_I\*V_I$
\end{center}
```

[image]

note that i have used the following packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in, top=0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}
```

These are the following error issued:

for `$V_I$ & $V_F$ & $P_F$ & $v_i$  \\ \hline\hline` ,

> Misplaced \noalign.

for other line in tabular environment

> Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.

please suggest what mistake is done and how to correct it.

I am beginner in latex by the way .

Thank you in advance!

the whole code is :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in, top=0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}

\title{\Huge \textbf{STERLING ENGINE}}
\author{\Large Name}
\date{30 August 2023}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{CALIBRATION}
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h!]
\Large
\centering
    $P_I=$1 atm\\
    $v_i=$2.2v\\
    \bigskip
    \begin{tabular}{|| C{2cm} | C{2cm} | C{2cm} | m{2cm} ||}\hline
    $V_I$ & $V_F$ & $P_F$ & $v_i$  \\ \hline\hline
    20mL     & 15mL     & atm      & 3.54v \\\hline
    20mL     & 10mL     & atm      & 6.2v  \\\hline
    20mL     & 18mL     & atm      & 3v    \\\hline
    15mL     & 10mL     & atm      & 4.2v  \\\hline
    10mL     & 5mL      & atm      & 5.8v  \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\Large $P_F\*V_F=P_I\*V_I$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try replacing `\centering` by `\centering\arraybackslash` in your column definition.

Comment: Your question would be much more convenient if it would have ready to copy+paste test documents instead of code fragments which one would need to puzzle together.

Comment: @JasperHabicht thank you it really worked!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of thinking about how to correct the situation.

- First, as @JasperHabicht has already pointed out in a comment, you could replace `\centering` with `\centering\arraybackslash` in the definition of the `C` column type, and keep employing the (now correctly defined) `C` column type in the header of the `tabular` environment.
- Second, taking the analysis to a much deeper level, you could conclude that the underlying `m` column type isn't quite right for the table at hand, since no automatic line breaking is needed in any of the cells. The second fix, then, would consist of employing the `w` column type -- which is also provided by the `array` package, just as the `m` column type is -- with options `c` (for centering) and the target width (here, 2cm).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for 'm' and 'w' column types
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | *{4}{ w{c}{2cm} | } } % 4 instances of 'w' col. type
\hline
    $V_I$    & $V_F$    & $P_F$    & $U_i$ \\ \hline\hline
    20\,mL     & 15\,mL     & atm      & 3.5\,V \\\hline
    20\,mL     & 10\,mL     & atm      & 6.2\,V  \\\hline
    20\,mL     & 18\,mL     & atm      & 3\phantom{.0}\,V    \\\hline
    15\,mL     & 10\,mL     & atm      & 4.2\,V  \\\hline
    10\,mL     & \phantom{0}5\,mL & atm & 5.8\,V  \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```